# MySQL double insert happeing in my php application

Tags: php, mysql

I have php application which gets information from a SAML POST and creates a record in the MySQL database, if the record is already present it just updates it

Here is the code

```
//getMemberRecord returns true for successful insertion.
$row = $this->getMemberRecord($data);
if ($row) {
   //if the row already exists
   $this->updateMemberRecord($data)
} else {
   // creates a new record
   $this->setMemberRecord($data);
}
```

This code is causing double inserts in the database, we don't have a unique key for the table due to some poor design constraints, but I see two HTTP posts in the access logs happening at the same time.

The create date column is same or differs by a second for the duplicate record.

This issue is happening for only select few, it works for most of them. 
The table is innoDB table and we can not use sessions on our architecture.

Any ideas of why this would happen

Comment: Is the code you've posted inside a loop? What database query does `setMemberRecord()` create?

Comment: `for successful insertion`, as in that method inserts into the database? Does `setMemberRecord` also insert into the db?

Comment: As Jasper says, we need to see the code for those get/set methods.  Also, I notice you are missing a semicolon after updateMemberRecord

Comment: the semicolon was a typo, i have posted the queries down below

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I see two HTTP posts in the access logs

1. You should try avoiding this and have just one http POST invocation
2. May be it is a problem related to concurrency and mutual exclusion. The provided code must be executed in a mutually exclusion zone, so you must use some semaphore / mutex to prevent simultaneous execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two HTTP POST happening your problem is not on the PHP/MYSQL side.

One thing is allowing a second 'transparent' HTTP POST in the HTTP protocol. It's the empty url. If you have an empty GET url in the page most browsers will replay the request which rendered the page. Some recent browser are not doing it, but most of them are still doing it (and it's the official way of HTTP). An empty GET url on a page is for example `<img src="">` or `< script url="">` but also an `url()` in a css file.

The fact you have one second between the two posts make me think it's what's happening for you. The POST response page is quite certainly containing an empty Get that the browser fill by replaying the POST... I hate this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the double inserts were happening becuase double submits and our application doesnot handle double submits efficiently, I read up on some articles on this, here are some of the solutions

it always best to handle double posts at the server side

best solution is to set a UNIQUE KEY on the table or do a INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

if you have sessions then use the unique token , one of the technique in this article
http://www.freeopenbook.com/php-hacks/phphks-CHP-6-SECT-6.html

or use can use the Post/Redirect/Get technique which will handle most double submit problems
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

note: the Double submit problem only happens on a POST request, GET request is immune

Answer (score -1):

```
public function setMemberRecord($data, $brand_id, $organization_id, $context = null)
{
    global $gRegDbManager;


    $sql = "insert into member ......"
    $gRegDbManager->DbQuery($sql);

    // Popuplate the iid from the insert
    $params['iid'] = $gRegDbManager->DbLastInsertId();

    $data =  some operations 
    return (int)$data;
}

public function getMemberRecord($field, $id, $brand_id, $organization_id, $organization_level_account = null)
{
    global $gRegDbManager;

    $field = mysql_escape_string($field);
    $id = mysql_escape_string($id);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_REGISTRATION_DATABASE . ".member WHERE $field = '$id' ";

    if($organization_level_account) {
        $sql .= "AND organization_fk = " . $organization_id;
    } else {
        $sql .= "AND brand_fk = " . $brand_id;
    }
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

    $results = $gRegDbManager->DbGetAll($sql);

    if(count($results) > 0) {
        return $results[0];
    }
    return;
}

/*     * ******************************************************************************************************
 * Updates member record in the member table
 * *******************************************************************************************************
 */

public function updateMemberRecord($id, $changes)
{
    global $gRegDbManager;
    $id = mysql_escape_string($id);

    if(!empty($changes)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE " . DB_REGISTRATION_DATABASE . ".member SET ";
        foreach($changes as $field => $value) {
            $sql .= mysql_escape_string($field) . " = '" . mysql_escape_string($value) . "', ";
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");
        $sql .= " WHERE iid = '$id'";

        $gRegDbManager->DbQuery($sql);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```